# Why does Nginx not just forward the POST request instead of 302

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I would like to test an Apache server through an Nginx proxy using jmeter. Get requests work correctly but for POST method Nginx responses 302 then redirects but instead of resending the request jmeter changes the method to GET. 
Why Nginx doesn't just forward the request like a client and gives back the response? Is there any way to fix it?

My application uses rest/json api calls.

```
        location /api {

            proxy_pass https://testserver;

            proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
            #proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


    }
```

Comment: There is no redirect here. Check your testserver

Comment: Btw, redirecting with 302 in response to POST after request is processed is a common practice

Comment: You are right, Nginx doesn't do any redirect but the server does. Can I avoid this somehow with header modification?

Comment: First You should find out why Apache sends redirect. Maybe there is a good reason and it works as intended

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have direct access to this apache server and  its administrators responses slowly so I would like to make a test on my own. It redirects my api calls form localhost/api/xy to https://server/api/xy